# Turn On GPS using NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, gps

I have read a lot of posts about managing GPS in android using code.
All of them saying that it is not possible. But they are all using android SDK to talk about the topic. Since it is not possible with SDK, can it be done using NDK?

I am asking this question, even after reading all those, because the android settings application can enable/disable it, which means it is not impossible.

In my app, it needs to turn GPS for a while and turn it off (for power reduction) and send the GPS data to a server.

Ultimately android is Linux based. So there must a way to turn it on/off using the Linux commands/APIs right? (or using the NDK) can anyone share the ideas about that?

If it is not at all possible (last option), is there any alternate way to get location information using any other functionalists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the Android NDK interface is much more limited than the SDK interface. To supplement it, you are able to access Java functions through the JNI interface. There is no extra functionality in the NDK that does not already exist in the Java SDK.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Steeve. So are you saying there is no other way to enable GPS automatically?

Comment: But my point is, the actual Android Settings Application can do it in some way. But why cant other Apps do the same?

Comment: @Hari I'm saying if you can't find a way to do it with the SDK, using the NDK won't help. I'd suggest posting another question about GPS...

Comment: Oh, then I will ask it as another question. Thank you.